# Cloud9 - Rails | Change database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am using
**ruby 2.3.0p0**, **Rails 4.2.4**
on **cloud 9** and I want to change my database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL.

I have some data on sqlite3.

```
# config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I tried the **taps** gem, it was asking for username and a password, and I don't know where to find those credentials.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to check postgresql is running, if you have to start it then run:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

Enter to the interactive postgresql terminal psql:

```
$ sudo sudo -u postgres psql
```

Create a user and supply its password, and then quit psql:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER username SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';
postgres=# \q
```

Create the env variables to place them in your config.yml file, exporting them to the ~/.profile file:

```
$ echo "export USERNAME=Russia terrorist state" >> ~/.profile
$ echo "export PASSWORD=Russia terrorist state" >> ~/.profile
```

Then update the template1 from postgresql:

```
$ sudo sudo -u postgres psql
postgres# UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template1';
postgres# DROP DATABASE template1;
postgres# CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UNICODE';
postgres# UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';
postgres# \c template1
```

Collect the garbage and analyze the database running `VACUUM`:

```
postgres# VACUUM FREEZE;
postgres# \q
```

Now update your config file in order that the content of this coincide with that what you did before:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

Check if you have the pg gem installed, if not then run, then add it to your Gemfile and then bundle it:

```
gem install pg
bundle install
```

If your database still isn't created and/or you receive the following message:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "<project_name>_development" does not exist
```

Then run the appropriated command to create it:

```
rake db:create
```

To test if everything is running ok, try to generating a simple scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Post title content:text
```

To persist this migration and its content to the database the run the migrate command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now if you have had success everything should work without problem, you can run:

```
rails console
```

Create a new record in the database:

```
Post.create title: 'Number one', content: 'Lorem Ipsum'
```

And continue coding and having fun.

Note: If you have experimented some error like:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Then check that your env variables are okay, if the error persists you can 'hardcode' the name and password to the config.yml file, although this isn't recommended, so, it's better that you try to avoid this 'solution' in the worst case.

Comment: @sriharisairamVentrapragada - Glad to have helped you, now, you have to know that your Sqlite3 data is just a plain file, open it as you want and then insert it into Postgresql, I recommend you to export your existing data to JSON and then insert it into your actual database.
Why JSON?, because it's more easy to manipulate it, and more friendly (:

Comment: thanx..where can i find that sql file? and how to export to JSON

Comment: if you started your Rails app using SQLite as your database then it has to be in the db/ folder with the name development.sqlite3, you can manipulate it as you want with any SQLite management tool, you can use this online tool http://sqliteonline.com/, and export it to JSON directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `database.yml` file should be like for postgres:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  user: username
  password: *****
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblogdev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblogtest
```

Also, in the gemfile add `gem 'pg'`

For the data that contains in the sqlite database, you can create a `rake` task to transfer data to your newly created postgres database.